# Erro ao tentar salvar registro no banco

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Após preencher o formulário e clicar em Salvar, está ocorrendo o erro abaixo:

```
mai 20, 2016 7:14:52 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
GRAVE: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /web/crud/cadastrar-habilidade.xhtml @16,80 value="#{habilidademb.habilidade.nome}": Target Unreachable, 'habilidade' returned null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getConverter(ComponentUtils.java:144)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:171)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1260)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1260)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel.processValidators(Panel.java:287)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1260)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1260)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'habilidade' returned null
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:124)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:58)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
    ... 38 more
```

Minha classe bean:

```
package br.com.evolutionary.controle;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import br.com.evolutionary.modelo.Habilidade;
import br.com.evolutionary.negocio.HabilidadeDAO;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "habilidademb")
public class ControleHabilidade {

    private Habilidade habilidade;
    private HabilidadeDAO dao;
    private Logger log;
    // Variáveis para receber o valor booleano do atributo habilidadeHidden
    private boolean habilidadeHidden;

    public Habilidade getHabilidade() {
        return habilidade;
    }

    public void setHabilidade(Habilidade habilidade) {
        this.habilidade = habilidade;
    }

    public HabilidadeDAO getDao() {
        return dao;
    }

    public void setDao(HabilidadeDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public boolean isHabilidadeHidden() {
        return habilidadeHidden;
    }

    public void setHabilidadeHidden(boolean habilidadeHidden) {
        this.habilidadeHidden = habilidadeHidden;
    }

    public void salvar() {
        habilidade = new Habilidade();
        FacesMessage facesMsg;
        try {
            if (habilidade.getId() == null) {
                dao.insert(habilidade);
                facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Habilidade cadastrada com sucesso!", "");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", facesMsg);
            } else {
                dao.update(habilidade);
                facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Habilidade alterada com sucesso!", "");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", facesMsg);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Erro:" + e.getMessage(), "");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", facesMsg);
            log.warning("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }

    public void novo(){
        habilidade = new Habilidade();
    }

}
```

Minha entidade:

```
package br.com.evolutionary.modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name="tb_habilidade")
public class Habilidade implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(length=20,nullable=false)
    private String nome;

    @NotNull
    @Column(length=150,nullable=false)
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name="efeito_secundario",nullable=true)
    private String efeitoSecundario;

    @Column(length=20,nullable=true)
    private String habilidadeHidden;

    @Column(length=150,nullable=true)
    private String descricaoHA;



    public Habilidade() {
        super();
    }

    public Habilidade(String nome, String descricao, String efeitoSecundario) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.efeitoSecundario = efeitoSecundario;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEfeitoSecundario() {
        return efeitoSecundario;
    }

    public void setEfeitoSecundario(String efeitoSecundario) {
        this.efeitoSecundario = efeitoSecundario;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getHabilidadeHidden() {
        return habilidadeHidden;
    }

    public void setHabilidadeHidden(String habilidadeHidden) {
        this.habilidadeHidden = habilidadeHidden;
    }

    public String getDescricaoHA() {
        return descricaoHA;
    }

    public void setDescricaoHA(String descricaoHA) {
        this.descricaoHA = descricaoHA;
    }



}
```

E o meu xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Cadastro</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="cadastro">
        <p:panel>
            <p:messages />
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel value="Nome: " rendered="true" />
                <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{habilidademb.habilidade.nome}" size="20" />
                <p:message for="nome" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Descrição: " rendered="true" />
                <p:inputTextarea id="descricao" value="#{habilidademb.habilidade.descricao}" rows="6" cols="20" />
                <p:message for="descricao" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Possui efeito secundário? : "/>
                <p:selectBooleanButton id="efeito" value="#{habilidademb.habilidadeHidden}" onLabel="Sim" offLabel="Não" style="width:60px" />
                <p:message for="efeito" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Efeito Secundário: " rendered="#{habilidademb.habilidadeHidden == true}"/>
                <p:inputTextarea id="secundario" value="#{habilidademb.habilidade.efeitoSecundario}" rows="6" cols="20" rendered="#{habilidademb.habilidadeHidden == true}" />
                <p:message for="secundario" />
                <p:commandButton action="#{habilidademb.salvar()}" value="Salvar"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua classe `Habilidade` possui dois construtores, conforme você declarou, porém, no método Salvar, você instanciou em `habilidade` somente pelo construtor padrão, que no caso, não atribuiu qualquer valor as propriedades da classe.

Inclusive, o atributos `nome` e `descrição` não aceitam nulo. Conforme declarou na classe `Habilidade`.

Quando fizer `get` em `habilidade`, ela estará `null`.

**Utilize:**

```
public void salvar() {
    habilidade = new Habilidade(nome, descricao, efeitoSecundario);
```